# How to access data from the repository.query() function?

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I am executing a query using repository.query('query', parameters) and returns me the expected result. However I am not able to access indivisual parameters within the result

I am getting this as result-

```
[
  {
      "title": "Prasad's 2nd Post",
      "content": "My second post",
      "advertiser_id": "1"
  },
  {
      "title": "Testin Post",
      "content": "Testing post content<html> </html>",
      "advertiser_id": "1"
  },
  {
      "title": "Testin Post 2",
      "content": "Testing post 2 content<html> </html>",
      "advertiser_id": "1"
  }
]
```

Does any body knows how to access the raw results returned by repository.query() method?

I am using postgres database, nestjs and typeorm

Comment: How you tried to do that?  Did it rise any error or something?

Comment: Used a for loop to traverse through above data and accessed it using result[i].title 
I dont know what was happening earlier, but now its working.